# Cannot retrieve verification code

Tags: iphone, apple-id

My Iphone 6 died. Trying to activate a different Iphone 6 with my sim card. Entered my Apple ID and password. Recieved message stating that the verification code had been sent to my trusted number (which is my phone that has died). Tried to then access the verification code from my Ipad which also sent the verification code to my phone that I cannot access. How do I move past this point since I cannot get to the verification code?

Comment: Have you tried to receive the verification code after putting in your sim card into the "new" iPhone 6 you have been trying to activate?

Answer (score 2):

Why not have your mobile company forward that number elsewhere, move the sim or set up a temporary device?

Apple’s FAQ covers what to do for recovering an account if it comes to that.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

Comment: I've kept a "burner" phone in my desk drawer for donkey years and the other day,  it came in handy because I had to assist someone with this exact issue and this answer is exactly how I solved it.  I put the SIM into the burner, got the text message and activated the phone.  +1